# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to get a base64 string MuleSoft

Tags: base64, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

[the dataweave code in MuleSoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjbmY.png)

[the request in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgkCd.png)

i just dont understand i have this same api deployed on cloudhub which is working perfectly fine but on localhost it is giving this error

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. Also provide details for reproduction as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also include versions of products used and the flow.